# how to get jmeter if controller to succeed 1 time every 20

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to get a jmeter if controller to execute a request one time in every 20. I'm not having much luck getting the syntax right. I've read the manual but find it confusing. Can someone help? I've tried:

${__counter() % 20 == 0}

and

${__counter()} % 20 == 0

and I've tried ticking and unticking the variable expression box which I don't really understand.

Grateful for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I got it to work:

${__counter(TRUE)} % 20 == 0

with the variable expression box unticked.

The function helper dialogue under options helped with getting the syntax right